# Python index like MATLAB's end/2

Tags: python, matlab, syntax

MATLAB has a very convenient syntax for getting half of a list:

```
x(1:end/2)
```

The syntax I know for python to do this is

```
x[:len(x)/2]
```

This is fine in this case, because `len(x)` is easy to write.  But this syntax becomes more than a pain when the name of the list is long (as they sometimes need to be), and even more so when there is a list of similar long names.

I know this is a real shot in the dark, but does python have any syntax option like MATLAB's?

Comment: I would point out that the syntax you ascribe to MATLAB is completely wrong. x[:end/2] will fail for several reasons. x(1:end/2) will succeed. Note the important differences.

Comment: @Mike: I corrected the code as woodchips noted. Also you should know that MATLAB (latest version at least) will issue a warning when the vector is of odd length. Ex: `x = 1:5; x(1:end/2)` will print `Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index`. You could easily silence it using: `x(1:fix(end/2))`

Comment: ... and obviously will fail in Python 3 as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specialized syntax.  If you need to do it a lot, write a function:

```
def half_list(l):
    return l[:len(l)/2]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, lists in python don't have the concept  `end`( a somewhat similar concept  is the index `-1`).
An easy (but not recommended) solution to your problem is:

```
l = longnamelist
l[:len(l)/2]
```

or to copy/paste the long name... (some editors have a shortcut for copying a word, this makes copy/paste of a long name very easy.)